# How to conditionally block event handler for the same element with vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I am using an external third-party script, which binds an event handler (`onclick` for instance) to an HTML element. In my script, I want to control if it fires or not, depending on a condition in my event handler for the same element. I tried `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` but it did not work. How can I do it using vanilla JS?

[Example on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wuzixideqi/edit?html,output):

```
<script> //third-party script, cannot edit
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  alert('clicked');
});
</script>
<script> //my script, can edit
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (document.getElementById('block').checked) {
    //block click event from third-party script
  }
});
</script>
```

In the code above, `alert('clicked')` is just an example. In reality there is much complicated logic which I cannot just paste into my event handler.

Comment: There is no way to remove anonymous event listener (which you have in your case) programmatically.

Comment: Unless obviously you recreate the element

Comment: @MehulMohan There must be the way!

Comment: Are you fine recreating the element? I mean you'll lose all associated event handlers with that if you do, but the ones you set later would work

Comment: @MehulMohan No, because the element is being controlled by a third-party library and it should work all the times except for some circumstances defined in my event handler.

Comment: I don't think that you can do it then.

Comment: @MehulMohan I found the way! See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround - dynamically create a child element covering all the desired element and bind an event handler to it. See this [example on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/gitusozuhu/edit?html,output):

```
<script> //my script, can edit
var inner = document.createElement('div');
inner.style.position = 'absolute';
inner.style.top = '0';
inner.style.bottom = '0';
inner.style.left = '0';
inner.style.right = '0';
inner.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (document.getElementById('block').checked) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
});
var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.style.position = 'relative';
test.appendChild(inner);
</script>
```

Comment: Haha yeah. That's a sort of hack. But if it works, it ain't stupid! :D